# react-native-fast-image with React hooks crashes onLoadEnd

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm using FastImage component from `react-native-fast-image` with React useState in callback.

like this

```
const Avatar = (props) => {
  const [isImageUploaded, setIsImageUploaded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={sizeStyle}>
      <FastImage
        source={{ uri: profileImg }}
        onLoadEnd={() => {
          setIsImageUploaded(true);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

`Avatar` component used inside `FlatList` and when I'm clearing its data I'm getting crash

[image]

Crash disappear without `setIsImageUploaded(true);` like

```
<FastImage
  source={{ uri: profileImg }}
  onLoadEnd={() => {
    // setIsImageUploaded(true);
  }}
/>
```

I'm new to React hooks. Any ideas on how to correctly deal with such cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added the check if callback isn't null, which resolves my problem.

```
- (void)setOnFastImageLoadEnd:(RCTDirectEventBlock)onFastImageLoadEnd {
    _onFastImageLoadEnd = onFastImageLoadEnd;
    if (self.hasCompleted && _onFastImageLoadEnd != NULL) {
        _onFastImageLoadEnd(@{});
    }
}
```

here my pull request https://github.com/troublediehard/react-native-fast-image/pull/1